# 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error in request js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, http, request

I'm writing an angular 2 app which uses a module called [github-trend](http://github.com/rhysd/node-github-trend). I have a service which calls some functions from the module

```
 scraper.scrapeTrendingRepos("").then(function(repos) {
 repos.forEach(function(repo) {
    //more code here
});
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

For now I'm testing my angular app with Chrome(56.0.2924.87) on `http://localhost:3000/` and its giving me an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, here is full message:

> Fetch API cannot load https://github.com/trending. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> data.service.ts:43 Failed to fetch

I've searched around and know that this might be happening because get request and server are working on differnt ports? Looking at the repo, the `github-trend` module using `requestjs` to make http requests but I'm not sure how to fix this. Is there a way I can make it work on chrome? What should I modify in the module code so as to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using an `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin` extension for chrome.